# Bokeh: Select row of ColumnDataSource using TextInput widget

Tags: javascript, python, input, bokeh, slickgrid

This is a pretty simple thing to do I imagine, but I'm not sure how to do it. 
I have a data table with three columns. Two are numerical values that are plotted, and one is strings. I want the user to be able to input into a field, and the corresponding row in the DataTable and the point on the plot to be selected/highlighted.

I think I need to use `source.selected.indices`, or possibly a CustomJS callback.

Can anyone help?

```
from random import randint
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn, TextInput

search_words = TextInput(title="Search for country")

data = dict(
    x=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
    y=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
    countries = ["France","Spain","Germany","Italy","Portugal","Poland","Russia","Bulgaria","Sweden","Belgium"]
)
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

columns = [
    TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
    TableColumn(field="y", title="y"),
    TableColumn(field="countries", title="Countries"),
]

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_select,reset"
fig = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools=TOOLS)
fig.circle('x', 'y', source=source,size=10,selection_color="red", hover_color="green")


data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

p = gridplot([fig],[data_table],
                    toolbar_location = "above")

show(row(p, search_words))
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that using the `show` method to render your charts you would need to use custom JavaScript to have a widget on the chart update data sources. The `show` method renders whatever has been programmed in the Python as an HTML document, but once rendered the HTML document has no way to further interact with the Python code.

The alternative is to use the Bokeh server, as [documented](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) here. Very basically, you can put all your code in a file `main.py`, put that file in a folder with your project name, and then in the terminal of the parent directory of that project folder, run:

`bokeh serve --show project_folder_name`

You'll also need to write an `on_change` method for your text input as described [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html).